# ClassNotFound error when building Fest with maven

Tags: java, maven, fest

Would like to try out fest 2.x branch. I'm not familiar with maven, but I downloaded fest from [github](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-assert-2.x), which gave me a pom.xml, so I ran maven with `mvn install`, and get the following:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building FEST Fluent Assertions (Core) 2.0M9-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ fest-assert-core ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ fest-assert-core ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/sbarnum/Java/fest-assert-2.x-master/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ fest-assert-core ---
[INFO] Compiling 180 source files to /Users/sbarnum/Java/fest-assert-2.x-master/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/sbarnum/Java/fest-assert-2.x-master/src/main/java/org/fest/assertions/internal/Numbers.java:[31,17] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Comparison
location: class org.fest.assertions.internal.Numbers<NUMBER>
[ERROR] /Users/sbarnum/Java/fest-assert-2.x-master/src/main/java/org/fest/assertions/error/ShouldContain.java:[38,6] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Comparison
location: class org.fest.assertions.error.ShouldContain
[ERROR] /Users/sbarnum/Java/fest-assert-2.x-master/src/main/java/org/fest/assertions/error/ShouldContain.java:[53,73] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Comparison
location: class org.fest.assertions.error.ShouldContain
```

What am I missing? Is it ungrateful of me to ask for just a downloadable .jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, based on the output from their [CI server](https://fest.ci.cloudbees.com/), that their build is currently broken, and has been broken since Dec 15th.  So nothing you did, they just have broken code in their repo.

You can pull the last successfully built jar out of their CI server [here](https://fest.ci.cloudbees.com/job/fest%20assert/org.easytesting%24fest-assert-core/), under "Last Successful Artifacts"

Answer (score 2):

Fest current build is very unstable as Alex (Fest creator) is doing a major refactoring.
He has pushed his unfinished work to be able to continue working on it hence the broken build.
I don't know when this refactoring will be finished.

Having said that, the common way to use Fest is to get the latest release from maven central repo (either using maven, gradle, ivy ....).

You can even download the jar directly from maven central repo **[there](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.easytesting%7Cfest-assert-core%7C2.0M8%7Cjar)**, nevertheless I would recommend using a build tools that can download transitive dependencies.

Cheers,

Joel Costigliola (fest commiter)

Comment: Actually, refactoring is supposed to improve the quality of the code without changing its runtime execution.  Odds are he's doing some changes while in the middle of refactoring, which while not ideal practices, often occurs.  That's why it has broken, the new stuff was probably injected during a refactoring bout.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it ungrateful of me to ask for just a downloadable .jar?

No, it isn't ungrateful to ask for a precompiled binary; but, if you are downloading source code and compiling, then you are picking the wrong item.

Perhaps they didn't release a precompiled binary, in which case I feel for you.  Basically this build is obviously broken for reasons that closely resemble "They started changing stuff but didn't finish the job", and you may either attempt to pull from an earlier snapshot of the repository, or fix the "whatever" that they didn't get around to.

Assuming that you don't care about the code, can you find the binaries you seek amongst http://code.google.com/p/fest/downloads/list?

Comment: Thanks Edwin, the links on there are for the 1.x version, which is not being developed further.

Comment: @SamBarnum True, but 2.x being under development in this case means, not yet released.  Basically you're getting stuff that might work for you (or in your case, might not even compile), but you need to beware _because even the development team doesn't think it's ready for prime time_.  That might be ok for your scenario, it might not.  Either way it will put more of the burden of quality control on your shoulders, and at this moment the code isn't of the minimum quality to successfully compile.